# Symbolic solution of differential equation with trigonometric initial conditions

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic, trigonometry

We observe that `D[Tanh[x3[t]], t] == Sech[x3[t]]^2 Derivative[1][x3][t]` and that `D[Sech[x3[t]], t] == -Sech[x3[t]] Tanh[x3[t]] Derivative[1][x3][t]`. We can express `x1[t] == Tanh[x3[t]]`, `x2[t] == Sech[x3[t]]` as solutions of the following differential equation.

```
DSolve[
  {x1'[t] == x2[t]^2 x3'[t],
   x2'[t] == -x1[t] x2[t] x3'[t],
   x1[0] == Tanh[x3[0]],
   x2[0] == Sech[x3[0]]},
  {x1[t], x2[t]},
  t,
  Assumptions -> {{x1[t], x2[t], x3[t], t} \[Element] Reals, t >= 0}
]
```

Unfortunately, `DSolve` outputs the warning "DSolve: For some branches of the general solution, unable to solve the conditions" and `{}` as a result.

Is there a way to make DSolve solve this differential equation?

**Update**

user64494 suggested to solve the differential equation without boundary condition, i.e.,

```
DSolve[
  {x1'[t] == x2[t]^2 x3'[t],
   x2'[t] == -x1[t] x2[t] x3'[t]},
  {x1[t], x2[t]},
  t
]
```

which yields

```
{{x2[t] -> -Sqrt[2 C[1] - 2 C[1] Tanh[Sqrt[2] Sqrt[C[1]] C[2] - Sqrt[2] Sqrt[C[1]] x3[t]]^2],
  x1[t] -> -Sqrt[2] Sqrt[C[1]] Tanh[Sqrt[2] Sqrt[C[1]] C[2] - Sqrt[2] Sqrt[C[1]] x3[t]]},
 {x2[t] -> Sqrt[2 C[1] - 2 C[1] Tanh[Sqrt[2] Sqrt[C[1]] C[2] - Sqrt[2] Sqrt[C[1]] x3[t]]^2],
  x1[t] -> -Sqrt[2] Sqrt[C[1]] Tanh[Sqrt[2] Sqrt[C[1]] C[2] - Sqrt[2] Sqrt[C[1]] x3[t]]}}
```

Choosing `C[1] == 1/2` and `C[2] == 0` yields

```
{{x2[t] -> -Sqrt[1 - Tanh[x3[t]]^2],
  x1[t] -> Tanh[x3[t]]},
 {x2[t] -> Sqrt[1 - Tanh[x3[t]]^2],
  x1[t] -> Tanh[x3[t]]}}
```

Since `Sqrt[1 - Tanh[x3[t]]^2] == Sech[x3[t]]` (if `x3[t]` is real), this assignment to `C[1]` and `C[2]` shows that the solution contains the boundary conditions above.

I tried running

```
DSolve[
  {x1'[t] == x2[t]^2 x3'[t],
   x2'[t] == -x1[t] x2[t] x3'[t],
   x1[0] == Tanh[x3[0]],
   x2[0] == Sqrt[1 - Tanh[x3[0]]^2]},
  {x1[t], x2[t]},
  t,
  Assumptions -> {{x1[t], x2[t], x3[t], t} \[Element] Reals, t >= 0}
]
```

which does not output the warning as the original formulation but has not yet terminated either.

Comment: Think of the result of `DSolve[{x1'[t] == x2[t]^2 x3'[t], 
  x2'[t] == -x1[t] x2[t] x3'[t]}, {x1[t], x2[t]}, t]`.

Comment: Using `Solve` to find an assignment of the constants `C[1]` and `C[2]` in the general solution such that the initial conditions in my post are satisfied is not possible. Was that your point?

Comment: Consider `/.C[2]->0` to this end. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: I updated my post with your hints. However, I am still not able to make `DSolve` solve the boundary value problem.

Comment: Every soft has its limitations. E.g. `DSolve[{x1'[t] == x2[t]^2 x3'[t], x2'[t] == -x1[t] x2[t] x3'[t], 
  x1[0] == a, x2[0] == Sqrt[1 - a^2]}, {x1[t], x2[t]}, t, 
 Assumptions -> a >= 0 && a <= 1]` produces a warning "DSolve::bvfail: For some branches of the general solution, unable to solve the conditions." and `{}`. That's life.

Comment: I appreciate your comment. Invariants are useful :)